# UI Testing with REST API

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, web-api-testing

I have one requirement in Automation to test UI and APIs at a time. Get parameters from the UI and pass them to API and get response.

Steps are like:

- Step 1: Enter text in the search field
- Step 2: Click on Search button
- step 3: Read text from the search field and pass to the API
- Step 4: Get the Response
- Step 5: Compare both UI and API response.

Is it possible by automation?

Please help me with your suggestions.

Comment: It's a bad idea to combine UI e2e and API testing at the same time. What is the use case that requires this combination.

Comment: By this concept, We will know, How the parameters passing to the API from UI and what is the response from API. And how the response updating in UI.  Simply, We will get exact issue of UI or API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Protractor E2E Testing to do so:

For **Step 1** to **Step 3**, you can use `'element selector in protractor'` to get or set text to any web elements. You can find the documentation here: https://www.protractortest.org/#/api

**For Step 4:**

You can use the `"http"` or `"request"` module to make the calls to the server. I recommend that the api calls return a promise so in the tests you can use the `browser.wait()` function and wait for the call to be fulfilled.

```
let apiCall = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get(url, function (error, response, json) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
               return resolve(JSON.parse(json));
            } else {
                return reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

And in your tests

```
it("validates something",()=>{
 //...
  browser.wait(apiCall(),timeout).then(json => {
              //do stuff with json
            });
 // Continue with your test
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any query. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I will try this one

Answer (score 0):

How about [Enly e2e runner](http://github.com/viant/endly/), you can define both UI and Rest API test, 
in your case you would just define w testing workflow:

endly test.yaml

@test.yaml

```
pipeline:
  init:
    action: selenium:start
    version: 3.4.0
    port: 8085
    sdk: jdk
    sdkVersion: 1.8
  testUI:
    action: selenium:run
    browser: firefox
    remoteSelenium:
      URL: http://127.0.0.1:8085
    commands:
      - get(http://UIEndpoint)
      - (#searchText).clear
      - (#searchText).sendKeys(my scarch criteria)
      - (#run).click
      - command: output = (#output).text
        exit: $output.Text:/done crtieria here/
        sleepTimeMs: 1000
        repeat: 10
      - close
    expect:
      output:
        Text: /may validate outut here/
  testREST:
    action: http/runner:send
      requests:
        - url: 'http://RESTAPIEndpoint'
          method: POST
          Body: ${testUI.output.Text}
          expect:
            Code: 200
```

References:

- [Endly selenium runner](https://github.com/viant/endly/tree/master/testing/runner/selenium)
- [Endly REST runner](https://github.com/viant/endly/tree/master/testing/runner/rest)